# Installation Validate class not found from basename 'StringLength'

Tags: install, zend-framework

I have an interesting phenomenon:

I tried to install Magento on http://www.fortrabbit.com/ but I get the following error. I'm sure on my first try it didn't happen, but the table creation broke at `max_execution_time`.

```
Validate class not found from basename 'StringLength'
```

I checked the file, it is there. I checked whether PHP enters the file, it does. I checked whether the name of the class is correct. It is.

Has anyone had this error before? I have no idea what to do. And I'm not sure, whether this site is the right place to ask for help. I think this problem might be really localized.

Update:

I tracked down to:

```
string(177) "Notice: iconv_strlen(): Wrong charset, conversion from `ISO-8859-1' to `UCS-4LE' is not allowed  in /htdocs/lib/Zend/Validate/StringLength.php on line 236"
```

Complete Error message:

```
Zend_Validate_Exception Object
(
[_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
[message:protected] => Validate class not found from basename 'StringLength'
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /htdocs/lib/Zend/Validate.php
[line:protected] => 244
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php
                [line] => 628
                [function] => is
                [class] => Zend_Validate
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => website_id
                        [1] => StringLength
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [max] => 30
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php
                [line] => 659
                [function] => _validateAttributeData
                [class] => Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [entity_type_id] => 1
                                [attribute_code] => website_id
                                [backend_model] => customer/customer_attribute_backend_website
                                [backend_type] => static
                                [backend_table] => 
                                [frontend_model] => 
                                [frontend_input] => select
                                [frontend_label] => Associate to Website
                                [frontend_class] => 
                                [source_model] => customer/customer_attribute_source_website
                                [is_required] => 1
                                [is_user_defined] => 0
                                [default_value] => 
                                [is_unique] => 0
                                [note] => 
                                [is_global] => 1
                                [is_visible] => 1
                                [is_system] => 1
                                [input_filter] => 
                                [multiline_count] => 0
                                [validate_rules] => 
                                [data_model] => 
                                [sort_order] => 10
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php
                [line] => 1187
                [function] => addAttribute
                [class] => Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => customer
                        [1] => website_id
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => static
                                [label] => Associate to Website
                                [input] => select
                                [source] => customer/customer_attribute_source_website
                                [backend] => customer/customer_attribute_backend_website
                                [sort_order] => 10
                                [position] => 10
                                [adminhtml_only] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php
                [line] => 866
                [function] => installEntities
                [class] => Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 624
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php
                    )

                [function] => include
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 421
                [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => install
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => 1.6.2.0.1
                    )

            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 327
                [function] => _installResourceDb
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1.6.2.0.1
                    )

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 235
                [function] => applyUpdates
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                [line] => 417
                [function] => applyAllUpdates
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                [line] => 343
                [function] => _initModules
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/app/Mage.php
                [line] => 683
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [scope_code] => 
                                [scope_type] => store
                                [options] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [file] => /htdocs/index.php
                [line] => 87
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => store
                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] => 
)

Error in file: "/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php" - Validate class not found from basename 'StringLength'

#0 /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645):  Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.2.0.1')
#2 /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.2.0.1')
#3 /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /htdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /htdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok don't ask me why but the problem is here:

```
$length = iconv_strlen($value);
```

I replaced the iconv_strlen with a strlen temporarly and now magento is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds more like you're running PHP in a `chroot` and you are missing required libraries for character encoding.

With the exception of a core bug in 1.3 - whenever we've been approached by someone with an `iconv` issue - it has always been due to a botched attempt of a PHP `chroot` - or fundamentally broken PHP/OS installation causing all kinds of charset issues.

The relative URL in your stack trace makes it look like it is a `chroot`. And if that is the case, then read more on what you ***actually** require for a PHP `chroot` to function properly - https://serverfault.com/a/430406/113375

Comment: sorry, i shortend the pathes. they were absolute /www/username/project/...